# Making sense of a watt meter reading

Tags: electrical

I attached a watt meter to my fridge and these are the readings after 4.5 days.

Usage 5.17 KwH

Hi 1500 W

104.5 W

.916 A

.99 Power Factor

116 V

Looks like the last four readings are a snapshot: V * A * PF = W

Since the readings took 4.5 days, I divided the KwH reading by 4.5 and came to 1.14 Kwh.

So would it be fair to say the fridge consumes on average 1.14 KwH every 24 hrs. with a surge of about 1500 W?

I'm also considering getting an inverter to power the fridge as a backup.

Given the above numbers, what's the minimum.

Thanks.

Comment: The 1500 is probably start up power, and depending on the fridge might happen quite a few times a day for about a minute each time.  I would want something more than 1500w.

Comment: Or it might be the defrost heater(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So would it be fair to say the fridge consumes on average 1.14 KwH every 24 hrs. with a surge of about 1500 W?

Yes, that is consistent with everything I know about fridges, including my own testing.  Mind you, these are units that do not have ice water in the door.

My rule of thumb has always been you need 1 kWH per day to run a fridge.